# WebSockets: String and Blob in single send message

Tags: javascript, websocket

I need to send message type with blob data in a single web socket message.

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://somedomain.com/data');

// just pseudocode
// I know that only DOMString|ArrayBuffer|Blob types are supported
socket.send({ type: 'someMessageType', data: someBlobData });
```

What is a best way to do it? First thought is to use JSON.stringify. But I think it considerabley increase the message length. Maybe there is a better way?

Comment: The best you can do is send the message as binary data.

Comment: @KurtPattyn Yes, I did a research and now I think you are right. There best I can do is to convert all data to BLOB, send it to the server and then convert BLOB back to the original data. Now the problem is how to convert BLOB data back to the original data on server (at least for NodeJS server)? I didn't find any blob converter library. Maybe it's time to write my own.

Answer (score -1):

You can convert your blob to base64 string using a FileReader. This is how you can do it in Dart. Sorry I don't know JS.

```dart
final FileReader reader = new FileReader();
reader.onLoadEnd.listen((e) {
    print(reader.result);
    socket.send({ type: 'someMessageType', data: reader.result });
});
reader.readAsDataUrl(file);
```